# PhantomJS crashes when running unit tests using Karma

Tags: karma-runner

I use Karma for running unit tests using framework Jasmine and PhantomJS. The problem is that PhantomJS is not releasing memory properly and when it exceeds 1GB then it crashes. It is probably same or very similar case as described here [PhantomJs Crashes while running with grunt-karma test cases ????/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28108839/phantomjs-crashes-while-running-with-grunt-karma-test-cases)

Based on https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/src/webpage.cpp I see that there is void *WebPage::clearMemoryCache()*.

Any idea how to trigger *clearMemoryCache* after run every *describe* in test?

I found that *node_modules\karma-phantomjs-launcher\index.js* has *self.specSuccess* method where I possiblu could force PhantomJS to clear memory. However, I can't find PhantomJS instance and even then how to execute *WebPage::clearMemoryCache()*.